# SEARCH and FETCH IMAP Command

Tags: vb.net, imap

I am developing a application to read email using IMAP protocol from my email server (Not google)
below are the sample codes. I am connecting to the server using TCPclient and now stuck on writing IMAP command

First

```
    c SEARCH NOT SEEN
```

SEARCH NOT SEEN does not actually retrieve the email which is not read. I just open my outlook and update my folder, it will update all mail to SEEN. How can I get the UID of email which is not read.

Second

```
    d FETCH 50 BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From To Subject)]
```

I am able to fetch the "FROM TO SUBJECT" of the email with UID 50. However, how can I retrieve the body of the email.

Comment: You can rephrase: How can you find out on which messages the Seen flag is set because a program correctly has set it, and on which messages the flag is set because Outlook has set it without any humans having read those messages.

Comment: I manage to find out why the flag has been set to seen... Yeah, just as arnt said Outlook will automatically set the flag as seen after they retrieve the email from the mail server

Answer (score 1):

Use UID SEARCH, SEARCH returns seqnos, not uids, UID SEARCH returns UIDs.